# How to sort by date magic field?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hi all I am a new of wordpress ,I dont want to sort my post by when I click published, I want to short it by my magic field date that I have custom by my selt call release_date . and here is my code below Help me please! thank you.

```
SELECT substr(meta_value,1,7) as Date
    FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."postmeta 
    WHERE meta_key = 'release_date' 
    AND meta_value <> ''
    AND meta_value >= '".date('Y-m-d')."' 
    GROUP BY substr(meta_value,1,7) 
    ORDER BY substr(meta_value,1,7) ASC
    LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for your queries. Here I made it so it orders it by release date ASC. And filtered out the older posts with the `meta_query`.

There are multiple examples in the codex which are not too hard to customize so they work for you. It's a good starting point when you are new to Wordpress

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key'   => 'release_date', // your meta_key
    'orderby'    => 'meta_value_date', // your type can be num, datetime,...
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array( // filter the query to show only posts from this day
        array(
            'key'     => 'release_date',
            'value'   => date( "Y-m-d" ), // change to how "event date" is stored
            'compare' => '>=',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Hi bro I copy it and replace ,but still see nothing, can u edit my code bro

Comment: @He7nG What is inside the $query variable ? Do you try to print the $query? You should do it like the loop.